# Find highest numbered filename in a directory where names start with digits

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ls

I have a directory with files that look like this:

```
001_something.php  002_something_else.php
004_xyz.php        005_do_good_to_others.php
```

I ultimately want to create a new, empty PHP file whose name starts with the next number in the series.

```
LIST=`exec ls $MY_DIR | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' | tr '\n' ' '`
```

The preceding code gives me a string like this:

```
LIST='001 002 004 005 '
```

I want to grab that 005, increment by one, and then use that number to generate the new filename.  How do I do that in BASH?

Comment: Is this to run as part of a web application? If the web server accepts multiple simultaneous requests (most do), how are you going to protect against the race condition when processes A and B do the check simultaneously and then create a file with the same number?

Comment: no this was part of a shell script to emulate the rails 'generate migration' tool, for a php app that uses a red-headed-stepchild implementation of the database migration pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ LIST=($LIST)
$ newfile=`printf %03d-whatever $((10#${LIST[${#LIST}]}+1))`
$ echo $newfile
006-whatever
```

So, that's bash-specific. Below is a *any-posix-shell-including-bash* solution, tho I imagine something simpler is possible.

```
$ cat /tmp/z
f () {
    eval echo \${$#} | sed -e 's/^0*//'
}
LIST='001 002 004 005 '
newname=`printf %03d-whatever $(($(f $LIST) + 1))`
echo $newname
$ sh /tmp/z
006-whatever
$
```

Comment: That's because numbers starting with "0" are *octal*.

Comment: +1. I would have stuck with the bash solution since that's a specific tag.

Answer (score 16):

Do you need the whole LIST?

If not

```
LAST=`exec ls $MY_DIR | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' | sort -n | tail -1`
```

will give you just the 005 part and

```
printf "%03d" `expr 1 + $LAST`
```

will print the next number in the sequence.

Comment: alternatively: printf "%03d" $(( 1 + $LAST ))

Comment: I didn't need the `exec` part

Answer (score 8):

Using only standard tools, the following will give you the prefix for the new file (006):

```
ls [0-9]* | sed 's/_/ _/' | sort -rn | awk '{printf "%03d", $1 + 1; exit}'
```

Comment: if the 001 file doesn't exist, shouldn't this command print out 001?

Comment: This doesn't work on directories containing many, many files - the output is: bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long

Comment: @John: Just replace the `ls [0-9]*` with `ls | grep ^[0-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be more simple.

```
ls [0-9]* | sort -rn | awk '{FS="_"; printf "%03d_new_file.php\n",$1+1;exit}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Fast, subshell-free and loop-free (also handles filenames with spaces)*:

```
list=([0-9]*)
last=${list[@]: -1}
nextnum=00$((10#${last%%[^0-9]*} + 1))
nextnum=${nextnum: -3}
touch ${nextnum}_a_new_file.php
```

Given your example files the output would be:

```
006_a_new_file.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ for file in *php; do last=${file%%_*} ; done
$ newfilename="test.php"
$ printf "%03d_%s" $((last+1)) $newfilename
006_test.php
```

i leave it to you to do the creation of new file

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   touch "newfile_$(printf "%03d" $(echo $(ls 00?_*.php|sed 's/_.*//'|sort -rn|head -1)+1|bc))"
   ```

   2.

   ```
   num=$(ls 00?*.php|sed 's/.*//'|sort -rn|head -1) 
   touch $(printf "newfile_%03d" $((num+1)))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer to propose a minimal solution to the core question "Find highest numbered filename in a directory where names start with digits":

```
ls -1 "$MyDir" | sort -hr | head -n 1
```

The first statement puts out the files in MyDir as one liners with the -1 option. This is piped to the sort function which sorts in human numeric order with -h and in reverse order (highest number first) with -r. This is piped to the head function which just delivers the -n top most results (1 in the example).
The answer considers human numeric sort order i.e. 221 is higher than 67. It is a POSIX shell solution so highly compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (you need bc):

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST='001 002 008 005 004 002 '
a=0

for f in $LIST
do
    t=$(echo $f + 1|bc)
    if [ $t -ge $a ]
    then
        a=$t
    fi
done

printf "%03d\n" $a
```

Comment: You can also use `dc`: t=$(echo $f 1+pq | dc), or `expr`: t=$(expr $f + 1), or bash math: t=$(($f + 1))